# (Using shared hosting for Wordpress in Hostgator) Installation failed: Could not create directory

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Can somebody help me, how should i create a a directory for plugins, there's already a folder created in Hostgator's Cpanel "Public_html>Wp_content>plugins".
But still if i install any plugin, this error pop ups "Installation failed: Could not create directory." please help, Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the permission to the folder.

When you installing any plugin it will uploaded to /wp-content/plugins directory.

Now there is three option to achieve this.

1) connect ssh and go to desire path and run chmod command

```
Chmod 777 -Rf /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
```

2) Open file manager from cpanel and go desire path and select folder and give the permission

3) creat a script which give me the folder permission. You can get that script on google

Here is one of the link :

https://gist.github.com/jasperf/5755794

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer, i changed the permissions of PLUGIN_ folder in Cpanel but it doesn't work. Please tell me how to copy the script that you provided and please tell where to copy it. Again thanks for your answer have a nice day sir :)